# django Error (EXTERNAL IP)

Tags: python, django, url

I am receiving notifications every time, when enter an address that does not exist.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/home/user/opt/local/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 100, in get_response
>     File "/web/blog/views.py", line 33, in post
>     File "/home/user/local/django/db/models/manager.py", line 132, in get
>     File "/home/user/opt/local/django/db/models/query.py", line 347, in get
>   DoesNotExist: Post matching query does not exist.

how to solve it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Modify your query to use [`get_object_or_404`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404), or catch the [`YourModel.DoesNotExist`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get) (3rd paragraph) exception when you're doing the lookup, and raise a [`Http404`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/#django.http.Http404) exception.  When you don't catch the `DoesNotExist` exception the view raises a 500 error.  As a side effect, this sends an exception email to the the [`ADMINS`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/?from=olddocs#admins) defined it `settings.py`.

Example of both cases:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

post_id = 1
post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=post_id)

# or catch the exception and do something with it

from django.http import Http404
try:
    post = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)
except Post.DoesNotExist:
    # id doesnt exist... do extra things here
    raise Http404
```

Answer (score 1):

The error was generated because your `get` query had failed to match any record. If you want to throw a `404` page in such an event, then [sdolan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6080024/django-error-external-ip/6080085#6080085) has already provided with you advice on how to do that. However, if you would like to assume some sensible defaults in the event that the query fails to fetch any matching records, you could wrap the call to `get` around a `try` and `catch` block. For example:

```
try:
    post = Post.object.get(pk=id)
except Post.DoesNotExist:
    post = None
    # Probably use some sensible defaults, or do something else
```

Answer (score 1):

use get_object_or_404 in query, see de documentation for more information.

> http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404

Answer (score 0):

I guess the main problem is in your view file,where you are working with http response request object .Check that all the settings are accurate in settings.py,also use try except block for finding the error more precisely.